# Restrict access for non-admin users and allow full access for admin users on SAME URL

Tags: wordpress, security, nginx-config

So.
The issue is that we have `example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` base URL that is used for search purpose and for tons of admin-related tasks (mostly Dashboard, plugins etc.).

So I am trying to figure out the way to restrict non-admin users to the URL alike 
`/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=woodmart_ajax_search&number=20&post_type=product&query={USER QUERY HERE}`
and allow admin users to use whatever URL there will be with `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

So far I was able to achieve the following:

```
http { ...
geo $wpadmin {
    default 0;
    127.0.1.1 1;
    192.168.1.2 1;
    192.168.1.3 1;
    192.168.1.4 1;
}
server {
...
location ~ /wp-admin/admin\-ajax\.php {

if ($wpadmin = 0) {
    set $test "user";
 }
if ($wpadmin = 1) {
    set $test "admin";
 }
if ($arg_action = "woodmart_ajax_search") {
    set $test "${test}+search";
 }
     if ($test != "user+search") {
       return "not allowed\n";
     }
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     fastcgi_pass ;
     fastcgi_index ;
     fastcgi_read_timeout ;
     include fastcgi_params;
     proxy_cache off;
    }
...
}
```

As you can see, the admin users are effectively restricted from using the `wp-admin` URL. I can't use fastcgi in the IF and I do not know how to be in that situation.

The same issue is going on with `wp-login.php`. WordPress is using a redirect to login administrator (`example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`)
As one may imagine using `if` causing normal users to be effectively restricted to login int the website.

I am a bit out of ideas with it... and am seeking for some public help. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, however the one piece of advice can give you is that it is rarely a good idea to attempt to change the core functionality of WP - it is a complex system and you don't know what is required by the internal code.

Comment: Sure, modifying WP is a hassle so that is why I'm just applying restrictions using nginx. So my goal is to restrict access to a certain WP functionality for the public and leave full functionality for admin users. The idea is that I want to block access to wp-admin/ the way that only 2 urls with determined arguments are allowed for public use.